# Is there a python function to read the files in folder by the order of modified time?

Tags: python-3.x, file, time

I have a folder with files, 1.pkl, 2.pkl, 11.pkl, 12.pkl, are created sequentially.

When use the code ‘os.listdir(path)’, to read the folder, the order of the file is：

1.pkl

11.pkl

12.pkl

2.pkl

How can I read the file in the order of the modified time ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [the `os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) and [the `sorted` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) together to achieve the effect efficiently:

```
entries = sorted(os.scandir(path), key=lambda ent: ent.stat().st_mtime)
```

If you don't need the other features of [the `DirEntry` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry) it produces, a simple `list` comprehension to change to the `.name` or `.path` attributes will solve it, e.g. to get the names (without the full path):

```
names = [ent.name for ent in entries]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `os.stat`

```py
path = '.'

import os

files_with_times = [(f, os.stat(f).st_mtime) for f in os.listdir(path)]
for f,t in sorted(files_with_times, key=lambda x: x[1]):
    print(f)
```

Comment: You don't need to manually decorate and undecorate like this; the `key` argument of `sorted` already does this for you (calculating each value exactly once, and reusing it); it's *why* they switched from `cmp` functions to `key` functions. A simple `sorted(files, key=lambda file: os.stat(file).st_mtime)` will do the work without Python level decorate-undecorate. `os.scandir` can do this more efficiently on some systems (as it gets the `mtime` info for free, without a separate `stat` call).